# How to determine the limiting distribution of $Y=(\bar{X})^2$, where $X=(X_1,...,X_n)$ and $X_i \overset{\mathrm{iid}}{\sim} \textrm{Unif}(0,1)$?

Tags: distributions, self-study, mathematical-statistics

For my introductory statistics class, I've been trying to determine the limiting distribution of $Y=(\bar{X})^2$, where $X_i \overset{\mathrm{iid}}{\sim}\textrm{ Unif}(0,1)~\forall ~i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$.

At first, I've tried to obtain some data by doing experiments with R, just to get an idea of what my result should look like. After plotting a good amount of samples on a density histogram, I concluded that the shape pretty much looked like a normal distribution, so I fitted the data on that model.

This is the R code I wrote:

```
means = c()

for(a in 1:5000) {
  x = runif(5000, 0, 1)
  means = c(means, mean(x)**2)
}

library(fitdistrplus)
normal_ = fitdist(means, "norm")

plot(normal_)
print(normal_$estimate)
```

This code outputs something along these lines:

```
       mean          sd 
0.249928052 0.004100903
```

The model seems to fit well as the QQ-plot is almost a perfect diagonal.

This being said, I couldn't find a way to express these empirical findings into something more formal. How can I calculate the asymptotic distribution in this case, from a theoretical point of view?

Comment: Are you familiar with the delta method?

Comment: @jld Unfortunately not yet, the course I'm taking is extremely condensed and many parts are left for research to us students. As a CompEng graduate my statistical skills are extremely basic, so I'm having quite a hard time

Comment: Make a guess: what is the limiting distribution of $\bar X$?  (The key is to find suitable normalizing sequences, because it should be intuitively clear--and rigorously follows from the laws of large numbers--that $\bar X$ has a *constant* limit, which is not terribly interesting to analyze.)  What does that suggest the limiting distribution of a suitable normalization of $(\bar X)^2$ ought to be?

Comment: @whuber By the CLT, I should have that $\bar{X}$ converges in distribution to a normal distribution $N(\mu, \frac{\sigma^2}{n})$. At this point I should be able to use the univariate delta method by considering $Y = g(\bar{X})$, hence $g(x)=x^2$. After some calculations I obtained that the limiting distribution is $N(\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{12n})$ because the variance of a uniform distribution from 0 to 1 is $\frac{1}{12}$, and its expected value is $\frac{1}{2}$. Is this correct?

Comment: The CLT doesn't say that (it makes no sense because with convergence, "$n$" is undefined), so please begin by reviewing what it does allow you to conclude.  Then note that the square of a Normally distributed variable does not have a Normal distribution: by definition, it is some form of a chi-squared(1) distribution.

Comment: @whuber I apologize, I was consulting the Wikipedia page and found the Lindeberg–Lévy version of the CLT, where $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\mu)$ converges to a normal distribution $N(0,\sigma^2)$, as $n \to \infty$. Is it correct to use this version in my case?

EDIT: mistyped the normal distribution's variance

Comment: Provided the assumptions of that theorem apply in this problem, you may safely use its conclusion.  You don't need any fancy version of the CLT, though, because your data are *iid.* To apply the CLT all you need to know is that the underlying uniform distribution has a finite variance.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Have a look at the mean and variance of the [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution) and use this to define the statistic:

$$Z_n \equiv \sqrt{12n} (\bar{X}_n - \tfrac{1}{2}),$$

giving you:

$$\bar{X}_n^2 = \frac{(Z_n + \sqrt{3n})^2}{{12n}}.$$

Now, have a think about how you can approximate the distribution of $Z_n$ and what the corresponding approximating distribution for $\bar{X}_n^2$ would be.  (Further hint: Using a normal distribution for the latter is asymptotically valid, but not a great option for good performance for lower values of $n$.  There is a much better approximating distribution that can be used here.)

Comment: Lovely clean answer. You may not need to go particularly high to get a fair approximation for modest tail probabilities from the normal -- from a QQ plot n=80ish is starting to look okay to me, - for most purposes I'd probably use it happily once n was over 100. However, given that it's fairly easy to use the approximation you're suggesting (and that works quite well for pretty small n; n=10 seems work pretty decently), it would seem odd not to take advantage of the benefit of that extra step.

Answer (score 4):

In the comments you are close to a correct answer. You already have that $\sqrt{n}\left(\bar{X}_n-\mu\right) \overset{d}{\rightarrow} \mathop{\mathcal{N}}\left(0, \sigma^2\right)$ by the Lindeberg–Lévy version of the CLT. You have also correctly calculated $\mu = \frac{1}{2}$ and $\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{12}$.
Now (with the suitably scaled sequence), using the delta method as described in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method#Univariate_delta_method) with $\mathop{g}\left(x\right) \mathrel{:=} x^2$ will work.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> You can ignore the assumption $g'(x) \neq 0$ if you allow for singular normal limits.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an extended comment in that a display is produced showing how close the normal approximation is to the true probability density function.  The density for $Y$ for any sample size can be found as a function of the Irwin-Hall distribution (the sum of independent uniform random variables).

I've programmed this in *Mathematica* but I'm sure it can be easily done in R, Matlab, Maple, etc.

```
p = ConstantArray[0, 15];
Do[
 dist = TransformedDistribution[(x/n)^2, x \[Distributed] UniformSumDistribution[n]];
 pdf = PDF[dist, y];
 pdfN = PDF[NormalDistribution[Mean[dist], StandardDeviation[dist]], y];
 pdfA = PDF[NormalDistribution[1/4, Sqrt[1/(12 n)]], y];
 p[[n]] = Plot[{pdf, pdfN, pdfA}, {y, 0, 1},
   PlotLegends -> {"pdf of \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[OverscriptBox[\(X\), \(_\)], \(2\)]\)", 
     "Normal approximation\nwith same mean and variance", "Asymptotic normal"},
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Black, Dotted}, Red},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 6}}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 14] &) /@ {"Y", "Probability density function"},
   PlotLabel -> Style["n = " <> ToString[n], Bold, 18]],
 {n, 1, 15}]

Export["display.gif", Flatten[{p, Reverse[p]}], 
 "DisplayDurations" -> 1]
```

[image: Display of pdf and approximations for various sample sizes]